# How to generate a PWM low frequency sine wave without a microcontroller

Tags: pwm, sine

I have a project (powered by a small battery) where I want an LED to slowly fade in and out.

For this effect, I want to make a PWM signal that resembles a sine wave.

Is there a method for this without using a microcontroller?

Comment: Of course there is, but you will spend much more in parts cost and design effort when creating a discrete version. You'll probably kill your battery a lot faster too. Use a small micro that has sleep modes.

Comment: You could probably do it with a couple of cmos 555 timers - one for the low freq astable and feed the cap voltage into pin 5 of another setup up to generate pwm.

Comment: @Kartman, I think your answer is really good but I'm not wise engouth to understand how I can put that into a circuit

Comment: A triangle wave will be much easier to generate and will give the effect you are seeking.

Comment: Drive the LED's with a triangle wave current (no PWM). Will be much easier on the eye. Flickery LED's drive me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to generate a PWM signal is to generate a triangle wave with an integrator and non-inverting schmitt trigger connected in a closed loop. Compare the triangle wave output with a variable dc level. The variable dc level is generated with a pot and the comparison is done with a comparator. No need for a sine wave.

If you want the LED to "breathe" automatically then you could drive it direct from the triangle wave. Something like this perhaps....

[image: LED breather]

Comment: Are you sure about this circuit and can it be adjusted to fit a 3V tension, because my simulation Software doesn't want to work, normally I should be testing it with real component but I don't have them and I need to make that into a PCB quickly because it's for a Gift

Comment: @leonllr I designed and built that circuit some years ago. I seem to remember I got it to work just fine. That circuit with the specified op amp and component values won't work with a 3V supply. If you need a 3V supply circuit You might be able to adjust the component values and use a rail to rail output op amp to get the output swing you need. But the principle of the circuit should still work on a 3V supply - that is a non-inverting schmitt trigger followed by a fed back integrator. In any event I would recommend building and testing the circuit on breadboard before designing a PCB.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly good sine wave must be generated by oscillators, when you don't want to use integrated circuits. There are lots of topologies for oscillators however, you can choose a simple one preferably without inductors. Maybe a Wien-Robinson-Bridge, a RC-oscillator or even a ring oscillator can fulfil your needs.

In most cases you then have to shift the levels and feed the sine oscillation into one input of a comparator while the other input is fed by a sawtooth or triangle generator.

The output of the comparator delivers then the desired PWM reflecting a sine wave.